# Algorithm to match two distant data sets for best performance in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following data sets:

A list of users.

`Tom, Lisa, Karen`

These users can manage any shop (one or more):

`Barba, Rentraum, Kisabran, Tespot and Lowvel`

These shops can provide any services/products:

`Yoga, Coffee, Mechanics, Gym`

These services can receive a complaint, which can only BE for ONE service at a given SHOP!

```
Complaint 1 -> Yoga at Kisa
Complaint 2 -> Yoga at Tesport
Complaint 2 -> Cofee at Barba
etc
```

Now, I want at any time to PASS the user_id (Tom, Lisa, Karen) to a query, and get all COMPLAINTS eligible to that user.

Comment: It seems you have two tables: one for links between managers and shops and the second one is compliant table which contains shop_id and service_id. You just need to create corresponding indexes to join them on shop_id and use filter on user_id.

Comment: Please replace verbal explaination about what tables and data you have, post all tables DDLs (including complaints table) as `CREATE TABLE` and data as `INSERT INTO`.  And show desired output for this data.

Comment: *These users can manage any shop (one or more):* What is the relation? Does more than one user may manage the same shop?